# Help understand the results of hough transform

Tags: edge-detection, hough-transform

I'm trying to apply the Hough transform of the following image using MATLAB:

[image: edges]

The result is:

[image]

How could I predict that there are 6 bright spots in the resulted image? I expected 8 spots since I observe 8 lines in the original image.

Comment: Try taking the Hough transform of only one side (ie your thick+thin line combo) and see how that looks!

Comment: I would expect four bright spots, since you will hardly able to distinguish the four line pairs by your eye only, since the line pairs have no gap between them. It becomes a "large blob". The points on the right is probably a kind of a "wrap-around" artifact: The first two dots are at an angle of 0°, which is the same at 180° - and you are probably close to 180° on the right edge.